# Troubleshooting CORS configuration for AWS Proxy Lambda Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to configure an AWS Lambda Proxy integration with AWS API Gateway. I've created all of the resources according to a couple of walkthroughs that I've found online, but the CORS pre-flight check is still failing. This was an attempt to migrate a API Gateway Proxy integration that I had created manually on AWS over to one managed by Terraform.

Looking at the UI of the two, I can't see the difference. Here's the terraform configuration for my API Gateway and Lambda function.

Does anyone see an issue and why cors wouldn't be accepting this? I've included the links that I've primarily relied on at the top.

```
    # Thanks https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-api-gateway
    # and https://dev.to/esenac/deploy-an-aws-lambda-function-in-go-with-terraform-12ap
    # https://medium.com/onfido-tech/aws-api-gateway-with-terraform-7a2bebe8b68f

    resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "chat_poc_api" {
      name = "chat-poc-api-terraform"
      description = "The API for the Chat POC Lambda"

      endpoint_configuration {
        types = ["REGIONAL"]
      }
    }

    resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "chat_poc_api_root" {
      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      parent_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.root_resource_id
      path_part = "initial_chat"
    }

    ### ANY ###

    resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "chat_poc_api_any" {
      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.chat_poc_api_root.id
      http_method = "ANY"
      authorization = "NONE"
    }

    resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_integration" {
      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.chat_poc_api_root.id
      http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.chat_poc_api_any.http_method
      integration_http_method = "ANY"
      type = "AWS_PROXY"
      uri = aws_lambda_function.initial_chat_lambda.invoke_arn
    }

    resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "chat_poc_api_any" {
      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.chat_poc_api_root.id
      http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.chat_poc_api_any.http_method
      status_code = "200"

      response_parameters = {
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true,
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true,
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = true
      }
    }

    resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "chat_poc_api_any" {
      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.chat_poc_api_root.id
      http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.chat_poc_api_any.http_method
      status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.chat_poc_api_any.status_code

      response_parameters = {
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" =  "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'",
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'"
      }

      depends_on = [
        aws_api_gateway_method.chat_poc_api_any,
        aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_integration
      ]
    }

    ### OPTIONS ###

    resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "cors" {
      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.chat_poc_api_root.id
      http_method = "OPTIONS"
      authorization = "NONE"
    }

    resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "cors_integration" {
      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.chat_poc_api_root.id
      http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.cors.http_method
      type = "MOCK"
    }

    resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "cors" {
      depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_method.cors]
      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.chat_poc_api_root.id
      http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.cors.http_method
      status_code = 200
      response_parameters = {
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true,
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true,
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = true
      }
      response_models = {
        "application/json" = "Empty"
      }
    }

    resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "cors" {
      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.chat_poc_api_root.id
      http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.cors.http_method
      status_code = 200

      response_parameters = {
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" =  "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'",
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'"
      }

      depends_on = [
        aws_api_gateway_method_response.cors,
        aws_api_gateway_method.cors,
        aws_api_gateway_integration.cors_integration
      ]
    }

    ### DEPLOYMENT ###

    resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "initial_chat_api" {
      depends_on = [
        aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_integration,
        aws_api_gateway_integration.cors_integration, # Add this line
      ]

      rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.chat_poc_api.id
      stage_name = "dev"
    }

    ### LAMBDA ###

    resource "aws_lambda_function" "initial_chat_lambda" {
      filename = var.initial_chat_lambda_zipfile_path
      function_name = "initialChat"
      role = var.lambda_bedrock_dev_role_arn
      handler = "bootstrap"
      runtime = "provided.al2023"
      timeout = var.lambda_bedrock_timeout
    }
```

I've tried tweaking the terraform configuration according to a variety of walkthroughs that I've found online, but I have not found the issue yet.

Comment: Are you making a GET http call to your lambda?
Because if so, it might not even be making the preflight request, and expecting the CORS headers to be returned in the lambda response